# Convert a "dotnet new Angular" project to net461?

Tags: angular, dotnet-cli

I have been playing around with the project created via

```
dotnet new Angular.
```

I love it!

But I need to reference a .net 4.6.1 project from my project. My first thought was to change the Angular project into a .net 4.6.1 project, as one 461 project can obviously reference another such.  So I tried changing the .csproj file, replacing

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

with

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>.
```

But then I get a bunch of build errors, starting with:

```
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0 is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0 supports: netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)   Angular C:\Code\Learning\angular\foo\AngularTest\Angular\Angular.csproj 1
```

If I remove the reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.All, I get errors from the code, saying that Microsoft.AspNetCore.All is missing.

I've used Angular with .net 4.6.1 before without problems. So there ought to be a way to do this. But what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can target `net461` in the Angular template, but you have to list the referenced assemblies separately in the *.csproj* file, rather than use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`.

It will look something like this toward the top of the file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I just did the switch myself, and it worked.

Comment: You made my day

Comment: Managed to get a Hello World program working. Do note that you may need to explicitly specify the .NET Core version 2.0, by creating the global.json file before running the " dotnet new angular" command.